# Remove the exact same matching lines with sed

Tags: bash, debian, sed, regular-expression, echo

I have this bash script:

```
sed -i -r '/deb http\:\/\/httpredir\.debian\.org\/debian jessie main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sed -i -r '/deb http\:\/\/httpredir\.debian\.org\/debian jessie\-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sed -i -r '/deb http\:\/\/security\.debian\.org jessie\/updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
echo -e 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\ndeb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free\ndeb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If I run in this order, there's no problem, the matching lines will be deleted from Debian's source list file. But if I echo-ing first, than deleting lines, it will remove line 5-7 also.

Changing SPACEs to \s not helping.

This can cause trouble in the future, when my Dockerfile not will be updated fast enough and Debian getting a new minor release.

Seems like if a global tag was being applied to this regex. Defining the line start and end also not helping in bash (although on regexr works great, this is what I want to get):
http://regexr.com/3b910

Seems like you can't define /igm flags with sed. sed still deleting the entire matching line.

EDIT:
I shortened this way, but I do something wrong because it's deleting everything from the file:

```
sed /etc/apt/sources.list -i -e '\!deb http://httpredir\.debian\.org/debian jessie main$!d' -e '\!deb http://httpredir\.debian\.org/debian jessie-updates main$!d' -e '\!deb http://security\.debian\.org jessie/updates main$!d' -e '$a \ndeb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\ndeb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free\ndeb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free'
```

This is my modification for the problem (the RUN command is Dockerfile script):

```
RUN sed -i '/^deb http\:\/\/httpredir\.debian\.org\/debian jessie main$\|^deb http\:\/\/httpredir\.debian\.org\/debian jessie\-updates main$\|^deb http\:\/\/security\.debian\.org jessie\/updates main$/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo -e 'deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\ndeb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free\ndeb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

The reason why I separating the deletion and echoing process, because maybe I will use this Dockerfile for another, some new super lightweight Linux distros, which not have sed default installed, but probably have echo. This way if I can't delete the lines, still echoing my modification.

The problem with multiline solution that I want to keep it lightweight (only one Dockerfile) and I don't want to include any external .sh script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sed patterns are not anchored on the end so they match the new lines. Another solution is to modify the lines instead of deleting and readding.

First let's see if we can make the original script a little more readable by not being so wide:

```
sed -i -r '/deb http\:\/\/httpredir\.debian\.org\/debian jessie main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sed -i -r '/deb http\:\/\/httpredir\.debian\.org\/debian jessie\-updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
sed -i -r '/deb http\:\/\/security\.debian\.org jessie\/updates main/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
cat >> /etc/apt/sources.list << EOF
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free
EOF
```

You know actually looking at it, there is no reason we can't do the whole thing with one sed command.

```
sed /etc/apt/sources.list -i \
  -e '\!deb http://httpredir\.debian\.org/debian jessie main$!d' \
  -e '\!deb http://httpredir\.debian\.org/debian jessie-updates main$!d' \
  -e '\!deb http://security\.debian\.org jessie/updates main$!d' \
  -e '$a \
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free\
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free\
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free\
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free\
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free\
deb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free'
```

So let's talk about what I did. First was to add the $ to the end of the patterns, although at this point it is not needed because with using a single sed command your race condition window is much narrower, maybe even removed because the original file stays in place until sed is done at which point sed copies its temp file over the original and this only happens once. next is to reduce the over escaping. specifically - and : are not special characters in either basic or extended regular expressions so they do not need escaping (and doing so can officially lead to undefined behavior per POSIX, but seldom does in practice). While we are at it there are a lot of slashes to be escaped so let's change our delimiter to ! since it is not used anywhere by using the \c match operator. And speaking of the differences between basic and extended regular expressions you are not using any of the contested operators, so it does not matter which your patterns are interpreted as so let's drop the -r option. Now since we are using multiple sed commands in a single sed invocation we need the -e option and we need it for each sed command. This has the added advantage in this case that the commands do not have to be before the files to be modified. And we finish it off with the a command to append the new lines, and we limit it with $ so we only do it at the last line. We could save six characters by not escaping . as it matches itself and is unlikely to match anything else do to the long patterns and the nature of urls, but good enough.

or here is a perl version:

```
perl -pi \
  -e 'next if m!deb http://httpredir\.debian\.org/debian jessie main$!;' \
  -e 'next if m!deb http://httpredir\.debian\.org/debian jessie-updates main$!;' \
  -e 'next if m!deb http://security\.debian\.org jessie/updates main$!;' \
  -e 'END print "
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free\n";}'
```

which can be one lined like this:

`perl -pie 'next if m!deb http://httpredir\.debian\.org/debian jessie main$!; next if m!deb http://httpredir\.debian\.org/debian jessie-updates main$!; next if m!deb http://security\.debian\.org jessie/updates main$!; END{ print "deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free\ndeb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free\ndeb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free\ndeb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free\ndeb-src http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main contrib non-free\n";}'`

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, this is great! One question: can you modify this to be one liner?

Comment: It technically is a one liner, but the a command   has to have backslash newline pairs to do what you want. it could be shortened by removing the backslash newline pairs before the -e options, but that would only save four lines.

Comment: I shortened to one liner, but I do something wrong because it's deleting everything from the file. Can you please check it? My reason heaving one liner is just I can easily enter the command in windows cmd, when I run Debian under Win Vagrant, Docker container.

Comment: \n does not have special meaning in this context you need a backslash newline. As for making it easy to type, do you have a webserver on the local network? if you do you can put the script on the web server and run it with `wget -O - www.local|bash`

Comment: This script will be in a Dockerfile, to fire up a new docker image (it will be debian:latest with a few personal modification, installing sudo, etc.). It will have "RUN" command in front of the code showed here, that will run on the image creation process. I don't know unfortunately if that Dockerfile can take multiline bash commands or not. It's possible to call external .sh scripts with Dockerfile also, but I try to make it lightweight (only one Dockerfile).

Comment: how about just replacing the sources.list file with an `echo "long line with \ns" > /etc/apt/sources.list`. by using a single > it overwrites the whole file with a new version.

Comment: hildred! The reason why I don't do this because I don't want to delete future release names when this file become outdated.

Comment: I suppose you could rewrite it in perl which has better escaping. see revision.

Comment: Dockerfile looks like can take multiline commands. See link: https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/ae130b2f845162fbf84da0ffad07d7a64eff57cd/5.6/apache/Dockerfile

Comment: I rethought my docker init process. The problem with external .sh scripts that the console logging not one by one, command by command. It's better to have the commands in the Dockerfile and separate the important ones by RUN line by line, this way you can see if something fails. Otherwise if you put everything into a one-liner command, or you use the \ line splitting, docker tossing you an error that the line failed and that's it. You just don't know what went wrong. The image creation with Dockerfile usually happening once, if there's no version update. So having more startup time no problem.